# Equivalent circuit for solar cell

Tags: diodes, solar-cell, pn-junction, model

I have a question regarding the equivalent circuit for a solar cell.
[image]

- [The circuit](http://org.ntnu.no/solarcells/pages/introduction.php) includes a diode to model the p-n junction of the cell. **When some part of the photo-generated current flows through the diode, what physical situation does it imply?** *Does it mean that the photo-generated electron-hole pair at the junction, move according to the depletion field (hole towards p-type and electrons towards n-type) giving rise to the photo-current and some portion of this current flows as a diffusion current (holes towards n-type and vice versa), creating the diode current?*

I just want qualitative arguments as an answer.

Comment: Doesn't the last paragraph of that linked page answer your first question?

Comment: @geometrikal It does, but I wanted to grasp the physical meaning of the surface current more rigorously. Rephrased in the question.