# How to connect photo diode to trans impedance amplifier?

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, photodiode, transimpedance

transimpedance example [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q-AZpagmtCw)

[image: from above video]

I need to design a trans-impedance amplifier to amplify the signal from a photodiode to make a PPG sensor 
I need a signal to acquire from the wrist.

photodiode I am going to use is SFH 7060

I don't understand how to connect anode and cathode of SFH 7060 to the amplifier input pin.

is it as follows?

connect pin 6 of SFH 7060 to (photodiode anode) inverting input of opa170?
and connect pin 7 to GND

do I need an instrumentation amplifier for this?

SFH 7060 [data sheet](https://www.osram.com/ecat/BIOFY%C2%AE%20SFH%207060/com/en/class_pim_web_catalog_103489/global/prd_pim_device_2220014/)
[image: from data sheet]

Comment: hat are you doing with the photodiode? Using it in photovoltaic mode, or reverse biased for maximum sensitivity and highest speed?

Comment: @Brian Drummond I don't understand those keywords. can you explain in an answer, please. how should I proceed to get maximum sensitivity from the mentioned sensor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Photo-current flow in the opposite direction to standard diode forward current so, if you want the op-amp output to rise when photo-current flows, you connect the anode to ground. If you want the op-amp output to fall when photo-current flows, you connect the cathode to ground.

Vout will rise in the schematic below when light hits the photo-diode: -

[image]

Equivalent circuit of a photodiode from [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/379828/equivalent-circuit-of-a-photodiode): -

[image]

Comment: dummy question how photodiode get energy? without supply voltage?

Comment: From the light itself exactly the same as a solar cell.